# numpy unable to understand

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Below is my code.

```
x = np.ones((3, 3))
print(x)
# [[1. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1.]]

print(x[:, [0, 1, 2, 2]])
# [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

I am not able to understand what has been done in second print statement. Please explain.

Comment: You are using the list as column indices, so you are retrieving columns, 0, 1, 2 and 2 again (along the x-axis). The colon is giving you the entire column / every row (y-axis). Try it with x = numpy.arrange(9).reshape((3,3)) instead to see what is happening.

Comment: @Benjamin Why don't you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Start with `x` with a variety of values.  It should help you see a pattern.

Comment: @LakshayGarg: because I voted to close... and still wanted to give a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [791]: x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [792]: x
Out[792]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
In [793]: x[:,[0,1,2,2]]
Out[793]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 5],
       [6, 7, 8, 8]])
```

The new array has copies of columns 0 and 1 and 2 copies of column 2.